# Summing with on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying count the total number of visitors to all restaurants in 2017(The total number of people to visit any restaurant, not individual restaurants). I only want to count the restaurants numbers if its store_id appears in the relation_table, but I can't get my code to work. I get a syntax error on "no_visitors"

UPDATE: My problem was with a previous line

```
total_visits = reservations.loc[reservations["store_id"].isin(relation_table["store_id"]) & (reservations.year==2017), "no_visitors"].sum()
```

Example dataframe

```
RESERVATIONS                            RELATION_TABLE       
  store_id   year    no_visitors          store_id
mcdonalds        2017       4             mcdonalds
kfc              2016       5             kfc
burgerking       2017       2
```

Comment: Can you explain more what not working? Because code seems OK.

Comment: hmmm, how working if omit `, "no_visitors"` ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to filter your data (`df`) is to do `df[filter_condition]` which returns the rows for which the given condition is true. Now all you need is to take the `sum` of the column you are interested in (`no_visitors`).

```
# df = reservations
df[(df.store_id != "") & (df.year == 2017)].no_visitors.sum()
```

Comment: Add context to increase quality of answer. It avoids flagging by bots or trigger user down-vote behavior. EoR.